# Applescript not working for pages on new computer

Tags: applescript

Running a brand new mac (OS 10.10.4) with Pages 5.5.3

I have always used Word for typing, but i'm going to try to get by with pages for now.

I often have to convert docs to PDF in batch and have always relied on applescript - not only can I not create a script to do that with pages, it seems Pages will not understand anything beyond 'open'/'activate':

```
tell application "Pages"
   activate
   set myDoc to front document
end tell
```

Returns:

```
error: "Pages got an error: Can't get document 1."
```

I have tried numerous other very simple scripts posted by others (who claim to use them successfully) to no avail. Is this a known issue? Am I missing something horribly simple?

Comment: I am using the same versions of Pages and OS and the code is working fine. Not sure what to advise next to solve the mystery...

Comment: @CRGreen thanks, this inspired me to update OS X (for whatever reason) and it worked (for whatever reason)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this same problem, I updated OS X software (which I hadn't done since I bought the computer) and it now works.

@CRGreen above points out that it works for him with `10.10.4`, mine is at `10.10.5` and works fine (don't think it's the version that was the issue, but perhaps some app support that didn't come preinstalled? who knows)

Also as a sidenote for anyone interested, the batch convert to PDF that works for pages is

```
open myFile
export document 1 to pdfFile as PDF
close document 1 saving no
```

If anyone can shed some light as to what was actually going on & post as an answer it'd be very welcome.